# SoundCloud waveform generation mechanics and display

Tags: ios, swift, audio, streaming, waveform

I am developing an app for iOS devices that is supposed to have a waveforms of music files like on SoundCloud. The problem is that I have achieved generation of waveform of fully downloaded file, how to generate a waveform of streaming audio during its playback? If someone's aware of how SoundCloud presents its waveforms please reply.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about SoundCloud,  for displaying an audio waveform, *what I think* is that they are -somehow- working with metadata for each specific audio to draw its desired waveform; Why it might be right? that's because the waveform will be drawn for each audio even before playing it (without waiting for streaming it). Applying the previous approach might be suitable solution for your issue.

However, I suggest to checkout [this library](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio#EZAudioPlot), it might contains what are you looking for (drawing the waveform while streaming the audio file).

Also checking [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699780/generating-waveform-from-any-music-file-ios) might be helpful to your case.

Hope this helped.